# WebGL shader program not valid

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Learning my first WebGL, attempting to draw an image (from url) on a canvas WebGL context.

My goal is to have a background image on the canvas with a transparent image on top, showing the background, to ultimately use captureStream.

While my shaders are compiling successfully (per gl.COMPILE_STATUS) it appears I'm missing a step to a valid program:

```
  const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
  gl.shaderSource(vs, document.getElementById('draw-image-vertex-shader').innerText)
  gl.compileShader(vs)

  const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
  gl.shaderSource(fs, document.getElementById('draw-image-fragment-shader').innerText)
  gl.compileShader(fs)

  var vs_success = gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  console.log( vs_success )

  var fs_success = gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  console.log( fs_success )

  const program = gl.createProgram()

  gl.useProgram(program)
```

I'm getting:

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid

Here are the shaders:

```
<script id="draw-image-vertex-shader" type="glsl">
  attribute vec4 a_position;
  attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
  uniform mat4 u_matrix;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  void main() {
     gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
     v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
  }
</script>
<script id="draw-image-fragment-shader" type="glsl">
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  uniform sampler2D u_texture;
  void main() {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
  }
</script>
```

Any insight would be amazing, big thanks :)

Comment: Most likely there was an error compiling or linking the shader. You need to show us the shader code.

Comment: Done! All I'm really trying to do is put an image as the background in cover:fit style fashion, but getting held up on just getting an image on the canvas.  The tutorials out there are old and missing a lot of assets. Thanks for any insight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach the shders to the program object and you must link the program object:

```js
const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
gl.shaderSource(vs, document.getElementById('draw-image-vertex-shader').innerText)
gl.compileShader(vs)
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) 
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));

const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
gl.shaderSource(fs, document.getElementById('draw-image-fragment-shader').innerText)
gl.compileShader(fs)
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) 
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));

const program = gl.createProgram()
gl.attachShader(program, vs)
gl.attachShader(program, fs)

gl.linkProgram(program)
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) 
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))

gl.useProgram(program)
```

Comment: Nice - we can ` console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))` collect logs !